# How do I get Yeoman to continuously run tests

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

When I run grunt server, my file edits are picked up and the browser refreshed through livereload.
When I run grunt test, it runs once and shuts down.

This behavior can be simulated by running

```
yo angular --minsafe mytest
grunt test
```

When I change karma.unit.singlerun = false in the Gruntfile, grunt test now says that a watcher is running, but no file changes seem to trigger running the tests again.

How do I get the reload capability with the tests similar to the way linemanjs works?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You were almost there! There's an additional option you can set in the Gruntfile called `autoWatch`, which monitors the files specified in your `karma.conf.js` for changes. A complete entry in your `Gruntfile` could look like this:

```
karma: {
  unit: {
    configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true,
    autoWatch: false
  },
  server: {
    configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: false,
    autoWatch: true
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome! works great. I did not understand the context of the tasks apparently.

Comment: It's easy to get this wrong, because the karma integration is a bit half-baked at the moment. Because karma and grunt have separate watching mechanisms, they currently don't work as well together as they should.

Comment: How do you get it to run the 'server' config instead of the 'unit' one?

Comment: in line that says grunt.registerTask('test, [... change 'karma' to karma:server'

Answer (score 0):

I set up as following

```
karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: false,
        autoWatch: true
      }
    }
```

It stands but can't rerun unit test when I change files, grunt karma:unit output

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux) Controller: MainCtrl should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope FAILED
        Expected 3 to be 100.
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.04 secs / 0.014 secs)
```

Found it: I use shared folder in Virtual and changing it outside virtual machine so that autoWatch can't recognize these changes.